# Using > with where clause in select statement

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have this query:

```
Select * from table_name where column_name > 'a'
```

I expect that the result should not contain names starting with 'a' but it does.
How does this query filter the results?

Comment: How do you think it does it?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Can you give an example of unexpected behaviour that confuses you?

Comment: I expect that the result should not contain names starting with 'a',
and if i use the 'A' instead of 'a' then it should return name which do not start with 'A' but in both the cases the result has rows starting with A

Comment: All words starting with `'a'` are (in a dictionary) after the letter `'a'`. So, that is expected. Perhaps you want to use `column_name >= 'b'`

Answer (score 2):

Using the collating sequence of the column `column_name`, it returns all rows that where the column_name value is greater than 'a'.  This would include 'aa' and 'aaa' for instance.  It would not include 'a'.

The most common collating sequence is the ASCII ordering.  In this ordering, the 'a' comes after all capital letters.  So this would return only values starting with 'a' plus some other character and greater through 'z' and including '{', '}', and '~'.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to avoid a from 1st letter of the column

```
Select * from table_name where column_name not like 'a%'
```

This is what i try on the parameter

```
Declare @strings varchar(50)
Select @strings ='ABCDEFG'
Select @strings where @strings not like 'a%'
```